A bounded set is Jordan Measurable if and only if its Boundary is Negligible
The following is a proof of the converse direction for the theorem, I do not understand why $$
bE_1 = C_1 \quad \text{and} \quad bE_2 = C_2. 
$$ And also why do the boundaries of  $E_1$ and $E_2$ consist of line segments parallel to the coordinate axes. Thanks in advance!
$$
$$
Let us assume that bA is a negligible set, and include it in the interior of an elementary set E , for which $ \mu(E) < \epsilon $. Then the boundary  bE   of E does not contain boundary points of A , and consequently, it can be expressed as:
$$
bE = C_1 \cup C_2,
$$
where:

$ C_1 $ consists only of external points of $ A $,
$ C_2 $ consists only of internal points of $ A $.

Let us define:
$$
E_1 = E \cup A^o \quad \text{and} \quad E_2 = E_1 \setminus E.
$$
Then we have:
$$
bE_1 = C_1 \quad \text{and} \quad bE_2 = C_2.
$$
Since the boundaries of $ E_1 $ and $ E_2 $ consist of line segments parallel to the coordinate axes, $ E_1 $ and $ E_2 $ are elementary sets. Moreover, it is easy to see that:
$$
E_2 \subset A \subset E_1,
$$
and:
$$
\mu(E_1) - \mu(E_2) = \mu(E) < \epsilon,
$$
which shows that $ A $ is a measurable set.

Just to clarify, you have a proof of one of the directions, and you someone to explain the proof?

That's a proof from a textbook, I understand the forward direction so I didn't add it, I do not understand one step from the backwards direction, I need someone to explain that step. I included the proof and I highlighted the step I do not understand.
